# Struct, Array Error C2512

Tags: c++

I am trying to do an assignment for my C++ class and am stuck. I have followed the book and searched the internet for answers but am falling short. I need to have an array inside a struct that will show a customer a breakfast menu with prices. They would select what they want and when they are done, it would display their bill. Here is what I have so far, which isn't much because of the error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int  main()
{
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

const string menuList[9]
{ "Plain Egg", "Bacon and Egg", "Muffin", "Frech Toast", "Fruit Basket",       "Cereal", "Coffee", "Tea" };

double prices[9]
{1.45, 2.45, 0.99, 1.99, 2.49, 0.69, 0.50, 0.75};

struct menuItemType
{
    const string menuList[9];
    double price;
    double tax;
};

menuItemType guestList;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the error message verbatim in your question. _C2512_ is pretty meaningless for non MVC compilers.

Comment: Error C2512: 'main::menuItemType' ; no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: `menuItemType::menuList` is `const`, so how do you expect to initialize it without giving `menuItemType` an explicit constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your struct above the main for one. Then call it in the main something like

```
menuItemType* guestlist = new menuItemType();
```

From what I can see this should help.

Comment: You are assigning `new` memory to a non-pointer (this is neither Java nor C#)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped. I moved the struct before the main and then used: menuItemType guestList(); and that fixed it.